# Android : open local map file

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I want my android app to open and to show a local file, representing a map, but not a **google-map** -like map (for example a building map http://herbarium.uvu.edu/images/MainMap.jpg)
But I want to have the same action available on the map, like point of interest, zoom in/out etc.

I read somewhere that I need to use
`new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);`

But I need to open a local file

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I'm currently using is '[mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge)'. 
They have nice little [tutorial](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Android-App.md) for android and server where you can find maps.

You download a map, save it on SD card and open it within code. Something like this works for me

```
private File getMapFile() {
    String MAPFILE = "map_x.map";
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mapsforge/", MAPFILE);
}
```

As for point of interest you just need to add extra layer with markers in it (according to the tutorial).
And now I want to pack .map file with apk and read it from there, but can't find some working solution (will update if I solve it).